# Looking for QT function to round a variable (integer) of type qint64 to the nearest ten

Tags: c++, qt, math, qt4

I'm looking for a QT function to round a variable (integer) of type qint64 to the nearest ten.

For example:
1013 would round to 1010.
1019 would round to 1020

QT Assistant doesn't seem to list any built in functions that would do this, but I could be looking in the wrong spot.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Wes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try this old trick for positive numbers, replace + with - for negative:

```
i_rounded = 10 * ((i + 5) / 10);
```

Comment: thanks.  lacking a built in function, this worked.  appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a very familiar with QT but what about

```
round(value/10)*10
```

does it work?

p.s: if value is integer, it may need to be converted to double before division.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to do this with integer (truncating) math is `10*((n+5)/10)`. That is for a positive number, of course.

```
n = 17:
17 + 5 = 22
22 / 10 = 2    // integer math truncates
2 * 10 = 20

n = 12:
12 + 5 = 17
17 / 10 = 1
1 * 10 = 10
```

For negative, add negative 5. So the formula is really `…+sign(n)*5` where sign returns -1, 0, or 1 depending on the sign of the number.